# How to set default item for combox in context menu strip?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, combobox, contextmenustrip

I have a context menu strip and it contains a combobox.
And I want to set a default selected item for this combobox.
I know get and set values for items in a context menu strip with a example as:

```
CtmAbc.Items(0).Text
```

But can't set selected item or add a event handler for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ComboBox index is 0, you can use the code below to set the selected item as the first item:

```
((contextMenuStrip1.Items[0]) as ToolStripComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Or you can also access the ComboBox by key:

```
((contextMenuStrip1.Items["myComboBox"]) as ToolStripComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0;
```